# Addition and removal of N-number File Inputs in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building out something that allows users to upload N-number of data files. In service of this, I've added a button that will create an additional file upload option. This is done with a simple for loop in the render function (there is a selection option that only appears if certain conditions are met, which is the 'mergeColumnSelection' variable, you can ignore that but I'm including it in case it somehow ends up being relevant):

```
let renderedEnrichedDataFields = [];
for(let i = 0; i < this.state.enrichedData.length; i++) {
  let mergeColumnSelection = ""
  if(this.state.enrichedData[i] !== null) {
      mergeColumnSelection = <div className="form-item__select form-item">
        <label className="form-label" htmlFor="add-target-owner">Merging Column</label>
        <div className="form-item__container">
          <select onChange={(e) => {this.setEnrichedMergeColumn(e, i)}} defaultValue={this.state.csvColumns[0]}>
            {mainDataColumns}
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
  }

  renderedEnrichedDataFields.push(
    <div className="form-group">
      <button onClick={() => {this.removeEnrichmentData(i)}} type="button" className="modal-close">
        <Icon name="close" />
      </button>
      <div className="form-item">
      <label className="form-label" htmlFor="add-target-csv">Enrichment Dataset</label>
        <input 
          className="csv-input" 
          type="file" 
          accept="text/csv" 
          onChange={(e) => {this.acceptNewEnrichedDataFile(e, i)}} 
        />
      </div>
      {mergeColumnSelection}

    </div>
  )
}
```

Basically, every time the button is pressed a new element is pushed into the enrichedData array in state. This causes the application to render an additional file input. When a user uploads a file, the placeholder element in the array is replaced with the file. When the user eventually submits the form, an array of files will be submitted which is great.

However! I'm having a lot of trouble getting a clean implementation for the ability to REMOVE these input fields. The function

```
removeEnrichmentData(index) {
  let enrichmentData = this.state.enrichedData
  let enrichedMergeColumns = this.state.enrichedMergeColumns;

  enrichmentData.splice(index, 1);
  enrichedMergeColumns.splice(index, 1)

  this.setState({enrichedData: enrichmentData, enrichedMergeColumns: enrichedMergeColumns});
}
```

As you can see this takes the index of the selected input, then splices it from the array that generates the for loop. The appropriate file is spliced from the array, and the number of file inputs is correct. However, there are problems with what file name is displayed. Pictures will help:

[image: Here you can see a sample where someone is preparing to upload three files, health, cluster, and starbucks]

> Here you can see a sample where someone is preparing to upload three
>   files, health, cluster, and starbucks

[image: Now I select to remove the cluster item (item 2) from the list. It is removed from the file list in state, leaving just health and starbucks. However, the for loop simply runs through twice and drops the last item - meaning that it appears that the health and cluster are the remaining two files, even though in actuality they are health and starbucks]

> Now I select to remove the cluster item (item 2) from the list. It is
>   removed from the file list in state, leaving just health and
>   starbucks. However, the for loop simply runs through twice and drops
>   the last item - meaning that it appears that the health and cluster
>   are the remaining two files, even though in actuality they are health
>   and starbucks

I thought about moving the JSX block itself into state so I can specifically target the JSX input element I want removed - but have had limited success with this approach and read that it's not advisable to put JSX into the state. React doesn't really have built in ways to easily delete the specific input, and I can't set default values in file inputs so I can't easily tie the individual inputs to their counterpart in state.

It feels like it should be such a simple problem and I'm very stuck. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure your `i` index is correct?

Comment: Yes I think so! You can see that I pass the 'i' from the for loop as the index argument for the removal. It always splices the right stuff from the store - but then when it loops through and rerenders it always chops off the LAST rendered item, instead of the one that was selected to be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Miloš Rašić is correct - your initial problem is that you're probably using array indices for the keys for the inputs.  So, if you have 10 inputs numbered 0...9, and you delete the input with index 5, you're still rendering items with keys 0..8, and React thinks the last one was removed.

Per your comment about using UUIDs, it sounds like you're generating unique IDs in the `render()` method itself.  **DO NOT DO THAT!**  *Never* generate random values for keys in `render()`.  When you do that, you're telling React every time that "this item is different than the last time we rendered, please destroy the existing item here and replace it with a new one".

Instead, you should generate these unique IDs *when you add a new entry into your state*.  For example:

```
class FileInputList extends Component {
    state = { inputs : [] }

    addNewFileInput = () => {
        const inputID = uuid();
        const newInputs = this.state.inputs.concat({id : inputID});
        this.setState({inputs : newInputs});
    }

    render() {
        const {inputs} = this.state;

        const inputList = inputs.map(inputEntry) => {
            return <input type="file" key={inputEntry.id} />
        });

        return inputList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to be sure without a fully working example, but this awfully similar to a "working" example of how React messes up when you don't give arrays of elements a key prop. Don't you get warnings about this from React? Try giving the divs you are pushing to the array a key prop which won't change for an existing element when an element is deleted (so key={i} won't work).

For example, if you are rendering

```
<input type="file" key={1} />
<input type="file" key={2} />
<input type="file" key={3} />
<input type="file" key={4} />
```

when you delete the one with key={2} it should be

```
<input type="file" key={1} />
<input type="file" key={3} />
<input type="file" key={4} />
```

Some sort of incrementing id like in relational databases or a generated unique id would do the trick.

Comment: That's a good thought. I tried substituting a UUID as the key, which, weirdly, prevents me from uploading any kind of file in the input! This led me further into the documentation where I discovered that input's of the file type are an Uncontrolled Component in React, so maybe I just need to rethink their inclusion and find a React friendly substitute.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
{this.removeEnrichmentData(index)}}
```

Here is a working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/2x4pl9m3wy).

Comment: My removeEnrichmentData currently accepts the index as an argument as splices it from the arrays. I think that's the same approach you're taking here, you can see my removeEnrichmentData(i) in the answer above.